# Sorting a list consisting of integer pairs

Tags: java, sorting

As the title suggests, I have a list consisting of pairs of integers (int ai and int bi). I want to sort this list based on only upon int a, while preserving the pairwise relationship. I was wondering if there was an efficient way to do this with some of the standard libraries Java has. Thanks in advance!

Edit:
My exact implementation is an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` in which each `ArrayList<Integer>` has exactly two integers (ai and bi). Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: What is the full  and exact type of your list? Is it `List<Integer>` or something else?

Comment: you can't have a list of int a and int b ONLY of Integer a, Integer b. I suspect your problem description is not correct... Tell us more about these pairs you use... how are they stored in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Collections `sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) or [Arrays `sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5b%5d,%20java.util.Comparator%29) method which takes a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and use a custom comparator which only inspects the first integer in the pair.

Something like this (roughly, depending on your exact types):

```java
Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<IntegerPair>() {
  @Override public int compare(IntegerPair x, IntegerPair y) {
    return x.first - y.first;
  }
});
```

Since the sorting algorithms are *stable* (per the Javadocs) your list will be sorted per your description.

Comment: You only needs `return x.first - y.first;`

Answer (score 0):

Implement http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html for your integer pairs and use sort() from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to create a class that represents integer pair. This class should implement Comparable. The use sort() to sort it.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a little safer to use the already-defined Integer compare:

```
Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<IntegerPair>() {
    @Override public int compare(IntegerPair x, IntegerPair y) {
        return Integer.compare(x.first, y.first);
    }
});
```